# Netmiko error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python

I received after attempting to essentially take a configuration file, cut it into lines, append it to a list, and attempt to push it to a router via SSH. Code snippets below.

```
device_ip = "192.168.1.5"
selected_cmd_file = open('{}.txt'.format("Router1"), 'rb')
print("[+] Pushing scenario configuration for device {}.".format("Router1))
command_set = []
selected_cmd_file.seek(0)
for each_line in selected_cmd_file.readlines():
    command_set.append(each_line)

net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type = device, ip = device_ip, username = radiususer, password = radiuspass)
output = net_connect.send_config_set(command_set)
net_connect.disconnect()
```

The output for the file contents after appending to the list looks like this:

`['!\n', 'version 15.6\n', '!\n', 'enable\r\n', 'configure terminal\r\n', 'no service timestamps debug uptime\r\n', 'no service timestamps log uptime\r\n', '!\r\n', 'hostname IOSV4\r\n', '!\r\n', 'no ip domain lookup\r\n', 'ip routing\r\n', 'ipv6 unicast-routing\r\n', '!\r\n', 'cdp run\r\n',line con 0\r\n', ' exec-timeout 0 0\r\n', ' logging synchronous\r\n', ' privilege level 15\r\n', ' no login\r\n', '!\r\n', 'line vty 0 4\r\n', ' privilege level 15\r\n', ' no login\r\n', '!\r\n', 'end\r\n', '\r\n', '\n', '!\n', 'end\n']`

I have ran this in the past and don't remember encountering this issue, so I'm not sure what I'm missing. This may help as well (File type shown from Linux)

```
file IOSV4.txt
IOSV4.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

Comment: 'rb' ? why use this method ?

Comment: Tried it with ‘r’ and ‘rb’. Same result.

Comment: Not match include_text vs file_encoding, create this file on linux and don't touch encoding system(create a file on windows and use on linux, don't do this, we talking about first 4 bytes on related `txt` file ).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is how I fixed it.

I recall there being a rule where files edited in Linux/Unix environments get a '\r\n' at the end of line, whereas Windows uses '\n', so it had to have been edited in multiple environments. Here is how I dealt with the above error knowing this:

```
device_ip = "192.168.1.5"
selected_cmd_file = open('{}.txt'.format("Router1"), 'rb')
print("[+] Pushing scenario configuration for device {}.".format("Router1))
command_set = []
selected_cmd_file.seek(0)
for each_line in selected_cmd_file.readlines():
    if '\r' not in each_line:
        each_line = each_line.strip('\n')
        each_line = ("{}\r\n".format(each_line))
        command_set.append(each_line)
    else:
        command_set.append(each_line)

net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type = device, ip = device_ip, username = radiususer, password = radiuspass)
output = net_connect.send_config_set(command_set)
net_connect.disconnect()
```

And the desired result:

`['!\r\n', 'version 15.6\r\n', '!\r\n', 'enable\r\n', 'configure terminal\r\n', 'no service timestamps debug uptime\r\n', 'no service timestamps log uptime\r\n', '!\r\n', 'hostname IOSV4\r\n', '!\r\n', 'no ip domain lookup\r\n', 'ip routing\r\n', 'ipv6 unicast-routing\r\n', '!\r\n', 'cdp run\r\n', 'line con 0\r\n', ' exec-timeout 0 0\r\n', ' logging synchronous\r\n', ' privilege level 15\r\n', ' no login\r\n', '!\r\n', 'line vty 0 4\r\n', ' privilege level 15\r\n', ' no login\r\n', '!\r\n', 'end\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n', '!\r\n', 'end\r\n']`